# How to uninstall a package by NuGet package console?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, owin

I have installed Microsoft Owin via nuget package manager console

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin

Now i want to uninstall the `Microsoft.Owin via` *nuget* package manager console

> PM> Uninstall-Package Microsoft.Owin

*but above line threw a error.*

*`The term 'Uninstall-Package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`*

**Is it pssible to uninstall via nuget console?**

Comment: Have you tried restarting visual studio to see if the issue still exists?

Comment: yeah, that's good... now i got another one problem . the error is 

`Unable to uninstall 'Microsoft.Owin 3.0.0' because 'Autofac.Owin 3.1.0' depends on it`

Comment: Unintall `Autofac.Owin 3.1.0` first

Comment: @RameshRajendran Do `Uninstall-Package Autofac.Owin -RemoveDependencies`

Comment: i want to uninstall everything with related to Owin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done by a workaround.

Once I uninstalled `Autofac.WebApi2.Owin` everything was gone.

```
Uninstall-Package Autofac.WebApi2.Owin -RemoveDependencies
```

Comment: Glad we could help :) .. for future reference there's a documenation [here](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/Package-Manager-Console-PowerShell-Reference) which is really useful

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `Uninstall‑Package <pkg id> –Force` to delete package when something else depends on it.